# What's the cleanest way to populate a template view in php while traversing multidimensional array data on the client side?

Tags: php, wordpress, multidimensional-array, foreach

**Precursor**: This is a bit of an in depth question. Apologies in advance.

I'm new to using PHP and since PHP is a product requirement, I need a little help.

**Overview**: I have a prototype template created and have imported my data as well as decoded it. You can view a `print_r()` version of that in the gist located [here.](https://gist.github.com/jshuadvd/f75f89a9b33334a5f29f63fdf8d6c4ad)

I have also created a multi-level `foreach` loop that allows me to get to the most bottom point of the dataset.

**Aside**: I know this is definitely not elegant, and I would appreciate suggestions of a more concise way to do this. I would assume a recursive solution, but not sure currently.

You can see this cringeworthy mess below:

```
function array_push_assoc(&$array, $key, $value){
    $array[$key] = $value;
    return $array;
}

$tab_names = array();
$products =array();

foreach ($connectors_session as $key => $val) {
foreach ($val as $k => $v) {        
    if ($k == 'name') {
        array_push($tab_names, $v);
    } elseif ($k == 'products') {
        foreach ($v as $pk => $pv) {
                array_push_assoc($products, $pk, $pv);
            foreach ($pv as $kp => $vp) {
                if($kp == 'series') {
                    foreach ($vp as $sk => $sv) {
                        foreach ($sv as $ks => $kv) {
                            if($ks == 'releases') {
                                foreach ($kv as $kr => $vr) {
                                    foreach ($vr as $rk => $rv) {
                                        if($rk == 'files') {
                                            foreach ($rv as $fk => $fv) {
                                                foreach ($fv as $kf => $vf) {
                                                    // echo $kf . ':'. $vf.'<br>';
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }

                    }
                }
            }               
        }
    } else {
    // Do something else
    }
  } 
}
```

**Pseudo code**: For each element, loop through, grab element by the key and populate the view area with said element. If the value of the element is an array, loop through the array, search for specific key, populate view, rinse repeat.

**Problem**: This all has to be done client side, without `JavaScript`.
I have created variables and am able to push certain values into those variables. This works for certain parts of the template, but I need to control the whole view (***see image example below***) at the Product level of the dataset.

The way the view works is that there is a container with a row and two columns. One column contains a set of nav links (each link is one of the products respective to the link name), and the second, on the right, contains form `<select>`s which should house the aforementioned products items. Similarly, the bottom green area resides in the initial container, but the contents should change based on the `<select>` inputs on the right.

**Thought Process:** I think if I traverse through the products section of the data, and populate my view based on that, I can meet requirements. With that being said, I have set a `foreach` loop to go through the products array I populated previously, which in my mind, should loop the whole view at the root container to cover all items inside.

When I enable the loop the whole view gets duplicated. I need to be able to loop through that part of the view and populate the items successfully, like I was able to do with the aforementioned variables I created. Any help would be greatly appreciated and again, I apologize in advance for this laundry list.

[image: View Image]

Please see the View template below:

```
    <?php //foreach($products as $key => $value) { ?>

<div class="col-7 col-lg-8 ">

    <div class="feature-description">

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-3 bg-light">

                <div class="nav flex-column nav-pills" id="v-pills-tab" role="tablist" aria-orientation="vertical">

                    <?php foreach($tab_names as $key => $value) { ?>

                        <?php if($key==0) { ?>

                            <a class="nav-link active" id="v-pills-home-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#v-pills-home" role="tab"
                            aria-controls="v-pills-home" aria-selected="true"><?=$value;?></a>

                        <?php }else{ ?>

                            <a class="nav-link" id="v-pills-profile-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#v-pills-profile" role="tab"
                            aria-controls="v-pills-profile" aria-selected="false"><?=$value;?></a>

                        <?php } ?>

                    <?php } ?>  

                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-9">

                <div class="tab-content" id="v-pills-tabContent">
                    <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="v-pills-home" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="v-pills-home-tab">
                        <p>Cillum ad ut irure tempor velit nostrud occaecat ullamco aliqua anim Lorem sint. Veniam sint duis
                            incididunt do esse magna
                            mollit excepteur laborum qui. Id id reprehenderit sit est eu aliqua occaecat quis et</p>

                        <p>velit excepteur laborum mollit dolore eiusmod.
                            Ipsum dolor in occaecat commodo et voluptate minim reprehenderit mollit pariatur. Deserunt non laborum
                            enim et cillum eu deserunt
                            excepteur ea incididunt minim occaecat.</p>

                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col">
                                <a href="">Link</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="v-pills-profile" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="v-pills-profile-tab">

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>

<div class="col-4 col-lg-4 ">
    <!-- <form> -->
    <div class="service-form">

        <div class="row h-100 justify-content-center align-items-center">

            <div class="col-xl-12 col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-12">

                <form>

                    <div class="form-group row">
                        <label for="select-item" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Client</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                            <select id="select-item" class="form-control">

                                <option>1</option>
                                <option>2</option>
                                <option>3</option>

                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group row">
                        <label for="select-item" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Version</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                            <select id="select-item" class="form-control">

                                <option>1</option>
                                <option>2</option>
                                <option>3</option>

                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </form>


            </div>

        </div>

    </div><!-- service-form -->

</div>

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg w-100 rounded p-4 text-white my-5" style="background: #acca42;">

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto text-white">
            <li class="nav-item pr-5">
                <a class="nav-link text-white" href="#">Download Link</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <a class="nav-link text-white" href="#">Download Size</a>
        <button class="btn my-2 my-sm-0 border border-white text-white" type="submit" style="background: transparent;">Download</button>

    </div>
</nav>

</div><!-- Content + Margins -->

<?php //} ?>
```

Comment: What's the use case here? Neither the array itself nor the nested `foreach` thingy look very promising to me, so maybe you can decouple your data sets a bit, ie. make the hierarchy more shallow?

Comment: @Michael I agree. I wish I could, unfortunately I can't as this is set up by client for their needs... :(

Comment: If your client cannot provide you with a more "workable" data structure, I would at least try to seperate your logic into several functions, like get_products(), get_series(), get_releases(), get_files() and so on. You could then apply these functions on the different elements of the array to get some sort of return values that you can pass on to your view.

Comment: @Michael I thought about this as well. My only issue then is associating the results from said functions with the indexes to make sure the full view has the correct information based on the relationship of the contents.